# React-router-v4 default route not working with Express backend

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router-v4

I'm using react-router-v4, React 16, and Express 4 for a web application. I use a BrowserRouter component for my main application to render all my routes. All of the component routes and the default route (404) render fine when requesting a single level subdirectory (`example.com/asdf`), but when one or more subdirectories are being requested (`example.com/asdf/zzz`), the default route fails to match the request and render, and I'm simply left with a blank page. Here is an example of my `app.js` with my routes:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter, Switch, Route
} from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <ScrollToTopRoute exact path="/" component={Cover}/>
          <ScrollToTopRoute path="/faq" component={FAQ}/>
          <ScrollToTopRoute path="/signup" component={Signup}/>
          <ScrollToTopRoute path="/login" component={Login}/>
          <Route component={FourOhFour} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Like I said, I'm using Express for hosting this web application. These are the relevant routes for that.

```
// Serve up index as React app under build dir
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

// Handles all other react routes so no 404 errors
app.get('/*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build/index.html'));
});
```

If I `console.log` inside of the `app.get` route, on nested subdirectories like `example.com/asdf/zzz`, it seems to loop 4-5 times before finally ending on a blank screen. I've tried removing all other routes besides the default route in `app.js`, and the results are the same, it works fine until nested subdirectories.

EDIT: Someone asked for my webpack config, so here it is:

```
// webpack.config.js
const HtmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  // Tell webpack to start bundling our app at src/index.js
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
    ],
  // Output our app to the dist/ directory
  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build")
  },
  // Emit source maps so we can debug our code in the browser
  devtool: 'source-map',
  // Tell webpack to run our source code through Babel
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|ico)$/,
      loader: 'file-loader?name=./public/img/[hash].[ext]'
    },
    {
      test: /\.(json)$/,
      loader: 'file-loader?name=./public/assets/[hash].[ext]'
    },
    {
      test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
      loader: 'file-loader?name=./public/fonts/[hash].[ext]'
    },
    {
      test: /\.(html)$/,
      options: {
        attrs: ['link:href']
      },
      loader: 'html-loader'
    }]
  },
  // Since Webpack only understands JavaScript, we need to
  // add a plugin to tell it how to handle html files.
  plugins: [
    // Configure HtmlPlugin to use our own index.html file
    // as a template.
    // Check out https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin
    // for the full list of options.
    new HtmlPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV'])
  ]
}
```

EDIT: Some more information. It seems like the Express routes are working, and rendering all non-existant routes using `response.sendFile`, but the default route appears to stop working when using nested subdirectories.

Comment: how did you set  up webpack?

Comment: Try removing the `'/'` from `use`: https://github.com/mikechabot/react-boilerplate/blob/master/server.js#L18

Comment: May be you can refractor error handling like suggested here: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/error-pages/index.js
So idea is, use middleware, as we define all routes define above error handling middleware, so if none of them match, final middleware should be called, which is error handling middleware.

Comment: Tried removing the `/` @lux, still the same. The problem seems to be that the Express route is working and rendering all non-existant route requests using `response.sendFile`, but for some reason the default route stops working on nested subdirectory paths. I simply get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` and the raw HTML file